# Non greedy and a fixed number of characters search and replace in VIM

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I have a number of strings which are something like this -

```
icon=null restored=0 title=Adblock Browser itemType=0 container=-101
```

I want to replace every string after the `=` such that there is a `|` separating two fields.

In the above example, I want the string to be replaced to -

```
icon=null |restored=0 |title=Adblock Browser |itemType=0 |container=-101
```

---

In VIM, I was trying the following `search-and-replace` expression -

```
:%s/=.\{-} \?.\{-} /\0|/gc
```

However, the problem here is that, it doesn't match `=Adblock Browser`, it ***only matches*** the `=Adblock` part.

---

About the part where I am using the `.\{-}` is because sometimes the strings are like this -

```
icon=null profileId=0 screen=0 modified=1462258474716 iconPackage=null iconResource=null spanX=1 cellX=2 displayMode=null appWidgetProvider=null intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.destination.main.MainActivity;end restored=0 title=Play Games itemType=0 container=8 iconType=null isShortcut=null spanY=1 _id=14 cellY=1 uri=null appWidgetId=-1
icon=null profileId=0 screen=1 modified=0 iconPackage=null iconResource=null spanX=1 cellX=3 displayMode=null appWidgetProvider=null intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity;end restored=0 title=Play Store itemType=0 container=-100 iconType=null isShortcut=null spanY=1 _id=15 cellY=3 uri=null appWidgetId=-1
icon=null profileId=0 screen=4 modified=0 iconPackage=null iconResource=null spanX=1 cellX=4 displayMode=null appWidgetProvider=null intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;package=org.adblockplus.browser;component=org.adblockplus.browser/.App;end restored=0 title=Adblock Browser itemType=0 container=-101 iconType=null isShortcut=null spanY=1 _id=19 cellY=0 uri=null appWidgetId=-1
```

and the output should be like this -

```
icon=null |profileId=0 |screen=0 |modified=1462258474716 |iconPackage=null |iconResource=null |spanX=1 |cellX=2 |displayMode=null |appWidgetProvider=null |intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.destination.main.MainActivity;end |restored=0 |title=Play Games |itemType=0 container=8 |iconType=null |isShortcut=null |spanY=1 |_id=14 |cellY=1 |uri=null |appWidgetId=-1
```

and similar for other strings.

---

### Minimal, Verifiable example

This is the content of the input file -

```
icon=null profileId=0 screen=4 modified=0 iconPackage=null iconResource=null spanX=1 cellX=4 displayMode=null appWidgetProvider=null intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;package=org.adblockplus.browser;component=org.adblockplus.browser/.App;end restored=0 title=Adblock Browser itemType=0 container=-101 iconType=null isShortcut=null spanY=1 _id=19 cellY=0 uri=null appWidgetId=-1
```

The search-and-replace expression in VIM -

```
:%s/=.\{-} \?.\{-} /\0|/gc
```

The Output:

```
icon=null |profileId=0 |screen=4 |modified=0 |iconPackage=null |iconResource=null |spanX=1 |cellX=4 |displayMode=null |appWidgetProvider=null |intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;package=org.adblockplus.browser;component=org.adblockplus.browser/.App;end |restored=0 |title=Adblock |Browser itemType=0 |container=-101 |iconType=null |isShortcut=null |spanY=1 |_id=19 |cellY=0 |uri=null |appWidgetId=-1
```

Erroneous part -

```
restored=0 |title=Adblock |Browser itemType=0 |container=-101 |
```

should have been -

```
restored=0 |title=Adblock Browser |itemType=0 |container=-101 |
```

Comment: `sed 's/[a-zA-Z]*=/|&/g' file` solves this, only that it adds a `|` at the very beginning.

Comment: @fedorqui as I have mentioned in the second part of my question, the strings are not very  straightforward. for e.g. 
`intent=#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.destination.main.MainActivity;end ` this has a lot of other characters apart from the normal `[a-zA-Z]` chars and adding `;` or `  ` messes the entire thing up.

Comment: OK I see. Then it would be good if you can [edit] and show a [mcve] covering all these cases, together with the expected output.

Comment: @fedorqui the question had the given input which caused the error as well as the error part. Anyways, I have updated the question with a Minimal Verifiable example.

Comment: From what I see, my initial suggestions makes it, you just have to remove the leading `|` afterwards.

Comment: How about this: `:%s/\s\zs\ze\S\+=/|/g`

Comment: @SatoKatsura Hey, this works, can you explain the regex?

Comment: Start at `=` and look to the left instead of trying to describe what should be to the right.  That's all there is to it.  Also, `\zs` and `\ze` are some of the most powerful operators in Vim regexps,  it's worth the effort to understand them on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/ ([^= ]*=)/ |\1/g' file
```

This will match a white space followed by 0 or more characters except white space or `=` then followed by `=`. 
The string captures inside the () brackets will be in `\1` ie first [capturing group](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/).
`\0` will have all string captured inside groups.
Then replace the match by `| \1`

Comment: This works. Can you explain the Regex. Also, what is the difference between `\0` and `\1` etc.

Comment: So you matched  <code> title=</code> instead of `=Adblock Browser `. That is clever.

Answer (score 1):

I have some bad news for you: in sed the quantors are greedy. You don't have lookaround either, so you cannot do it in sed.

Good news: perl can help you with this. Here is a script that implements almost everything with perl:

```
echo "icon=null restored=0 title=Adblock Browser itemType=0 container=-101" |
perl -p -e 's/([^ =]*=)/|\1/g'
```

Unfortunately it'll have a leading pipe. But that's easy to fix - but a little dirty, I know:

```
echo "icon=null restored=0 title=Adblock Browser itemType=0 container=-101" |
perl -p -e 's/([^ =]*=)/|\1/g' | 
sed 's/^|//g'
```